Jasper Reports: how to pass JSON as InputStream using REST API
I'm trying to pass JSON string as InputStream to Jasper Reports template using its REST API and can't make it work: sometimes template is just empty (no data), sometimes has null values, sometimes I get error while printing.
Important thing that we don't use any JasperReports library, just their REST API.
Here what I have.
Parameters in request to Jasper server (Java side):
String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"One\", \"age\":Two, \"car\":Three}";
InputStream iostream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
reportData.put("data", iostream);

Request payload to Jasper Server:
{
    "reportUnitUri": "/reports/***/v1/***",
    "outputFormat": "pdf",
    "async": false,
    "freshData": true,
    "saveDataSnapshot": false,
    "interactive": true,
    "allowInlineScripts": true,
    "ignorePagination": false,
    "pages": null,
    "attachmentsPrefix": null,
    "parameters":
    {
        "reportParameter":
        [
            {
                "name": "data",
                "value":
                [
                    "java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@7f8e1831"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

Jasper template:
<parameter name="data" class="java.io.InputStream"/>
<field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="data.name"/>
...also tried...
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="name"/>
</field>

Result: empty report.
Tried to use fake mock values - it works, prints, but can't grab anything from "data" parameter:
    <parameter name="mock" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["{\"mock\":[{\"mockId\": \"1\"}]}"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="JSON_INPUT_STREAM" class="java.io.InputStream">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream($P{mock}.getBytes("UTF-8"))]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="data" class="java.io.InputStream"/>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="mockId" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[mockId]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>

Tried to use JsonDatasource type - <parameter name="data" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource"/> - result: broken report.
Tried to use JSON_INPUT_STREAM parameter name and pass it from Java code, but it breaks report too.
Overall, after printing report with different combinations of parameters I got either blank page and "No data" section filled (for test purposes), or filled page, but null value for parameter.
The only variant that works is:

Pass report parameter as JSON string

String datasetJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dataSet.getData());
reportData.put("reportData", datasetJson);


In report template process it this way:

    <parameter name="reportData" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="JSON_INPUT_STREAM" class="java.io.InputStream">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream($P{reportData}.getBytes("UTF-8"))]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>

And this works. But as you can see, I cast my string to new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream which is not good. Why not to read stream from parameter map?
So my question is: how to pass data stream to report template correctly? If data stream is not easy to use, I can try to switch to passing object, insted of stream. Please, help me to find what am I doing wrong.
Thanks in advance!
Also tried this answers:

How to fill report using JSON datasource without getting null values?
Filling reports from json using JasperReports
Jasper Report - Passing json IO stream to subreport
https://community.jaspersoft.com/forums/topic/65690-passing-json-stream-as-datasource-to-subreport/
How to pass json data to jasper report using rest


You're missing the query in your "mock" attempt.  This should work:
<parameter name="mock" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["{\"mock\":[{\"mockId\": \"1\"}]}"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="JSON_INPUT_STREAM" class="java.io.InputStream">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream($P{mock}.getBytes("UTF-8"))]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString language="json">
    <![CDATA[mock]]>
</queryString>
<field name="mockId" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[mockId]]></fieldDescription>
</field>

With this report, you can pass a String value for the "mock" parameter in the report execution request.  As in
{
  "reportUnitUri": "...",
  ...
  "parameters": {
    "reportParameter": [
      {
        "name": "mock",
        "value": [
          "{\"mock\":[{\"mockId\": \"2\"}]}"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

